# SELECT query with CASE condition and SUM()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, case, conditional-statements

I'm currently using these sql statements. My table has the field CPaymentType which contains "Cash" or "Check". I can sum up the amount of payments by executing 2 SQL statements as shown below. In this case, the user won't even notice the speed difference when executing 2 sql statements or just 1, however, I don't like my way, I just want 1 sql statement. How do I reconstruct these into 1 statement with CASE conditions? I can't figure it out since examples online result in either 1 or 0 or boolean. I don't want the postdated Check payments to be included. Thank you very much.

```
Select SUM(CAmount) as PaymentAmount 
from TableOrderPayment 
where CPaymentType='Cash' and CStatus='Active';

Select SUM(CAmount) as PaymentAmount 
from TableOrderPayment 
where CPaymentType='Check' and CDate<=SYSDATETIME() and CStatus='Active';
```

Comment: If you don't want post dated cheques in your results, your 2nd query appears to achieve that.  What don't you like about it?

Comment: Yeah, I already achieved what I want. However, I don't like using 2 sql statements. I want these 2 to be merged into 1 statement with CASE conditions :)

Comment: btw: "case expression" is the more correct term.  (An "expression" evaluates to a single value.)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
Select SUM(CASE When CPayment='Cash' Then CAmount Else 0 End ) as CashPaymentAmount,
       SUM(CASE When CPayment='Check' Then CAmount Else 0 End ) as CheckPaymentAmount
from TableOrderPayment
Where ( CPayment='Cash' Or CPayment='Check' ) AND CDate<=SYSDATETIME() and CStatus='Active';
```

Comment: Thank you for all your answers, all are correct, but I'd choose this 1 since I was looking for something with the CASE statement. I've never used the CASE statement which is why I want to try this example. I just made 2 sql statements so my point would easily be understood. Thank you Sir!

Comment: @chris_techno25 In regards to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3732435) I suggest, since you are a new user, you go through [Does this amount to inconsistency in the edit review process?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182419/221866) and [Clarification of edit rejection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179655/221866), [meta] discussions.

Comment: Correct one if we want to use CASE statement. Thank you for making our results correct @mudassir-hasan

Answer (score 6):

```
select CPaymentType, sum(CAmount)
from TableOrderPayment
where (CPaymentType = 'Cash' and CStatus = 'Active')
or (CPaymentType = 'Check' and CDate <= bsysdatetime() abd CStatus = 'Active')
group by CPaymentType
```

Cheers -

Answer (score 5):

To get each sum in a separate column:

```
Select SUM(IF(CPaymentType='Check', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCheck,
       SUM(IF(CPaymentType='Cash', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCash
from TableOrderPayment
where CPaymentType IN ('Check','Cash') 
and CDate<=SYSDATETIME() 
and CStatus='Active';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an "Or"

```
Select SUM(CAmount) as PaymentAmount 
from TableOrderPayment 
where (CPaymentType='Check' Or CPaymentType='Cash')
   and CDate <= case CPaymentType When 'Check' Then SYSDATETIME() else CDate End
   and CStatus='" & "Active" & "'"
```

or an "IN"

```
Select SUM(CAmount) as PaymentAmount 
from TableOrderPayment 
where CPaymentType IN ('Check', 'Cash')
   and CDate <= case CPaymentType When 'Check' Then SYSDATETIME() else CDate End
   and CStatus='" & "Active" & "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a case statement.  You just need to update your where clause and make sure you have correct parentheses to group the clauses.

```
SELECT Sum(CAMount) as PaymentAmount 
from TableOrderPayment 
where (CStatus = 'Active' AND CPaymentType = 'Cash') 
OR (CStatus = 'Active' and CPaymentType = 'Check' and CDate<=SYSDATETIME())
```

The answers posted before mine assume that CDate<=SYSDATETIME() is also appropriate for Cash payment type as well.  I think I split mine out so it only looks for that clause for check payments.