# Dealing with comma separated value in group by clause

Tags: mysql

I have a column named `purchasetype` which contains three kind of values `new`,`trial`,`new,trial` another column in `noofsales`
I am counting the total number based on the `purchasetype`
The query I am using is

```
   Select SUM(noofsales) 
     From table 
  GroupBy purchasetype
```

This query is giving me 3 kind of sum result `new`,`trial` and `new,trial`
I want total sum in `new` and `trial` only if one record contains `new,trial` then one count should increase for `new` and also one count should increase for `trial`
I have tried using substring_index function like

```
Select SUM(noofsales) 
     From table 
  Groupby substring_index(PurchaseType, ',', 0)
```

but this is summing up only for the first record in comma separated value.

Comment: use sum(if(condition, 1, 0)), you have examples here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075505/mysql-is-it-possible-to-sum-if-or-to-count-if

Comment: Can't we do anything in the group by section?

Comment: you can group by anything you want

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can use CASE/WHEN statement for each sum. For example:

[SELECT query with CASE condition and SUM()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935265/select-query-with-case-condition-and-sum)

Comment: purchase type is having so many values, I have just given a simple example

Comment: Can't we do it by changing the group by clause?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a number table on the fly, and use it to turn records where `purchase_type` is a comma separated value into new rows. Then in the outer query you can aggregate properly.

Consider the following query, that you can see in action in [this db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8ab48bc6875e94cf355ae9b016927cd0). It will dynamically discover the available purchase types and generate the result that you expect :

```
SELECT x.purchase_type, SUM(x.noofsale)
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.noofsale,
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.purchase_type, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) purchase_type
    FROM
        (SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2) numbers 
        INNER JOIN t ON CHAR_LENGTH(t.purchase_type) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(t.purchase_type, ',', ''))>= numbers.n-1
) x
GROUP BY x.purchase_type
ORDER BY 1,2
```

NB : this query supports maximum two comma-separated values (as shown in your sample data) ; if you expected more than that, you may adapt the `numbers` subquery :

```
(SELECT 1 n UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 ...)
```