# Sum of case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

```
Select SUM(IF(CPaymentType='Check', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCheck, 
       SUM(IF(CPaymentType='Cash', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCash 
from TableOrderPayment 
where CPaymentType IN ('Check','Cash') and CDate<=SYSDATETIME() and CStatus='Active';
```

I want to sum PaymentAmountCheck and PaymentAmountCash, can anyone help me please

Comment: Is the query not return the expected result or any error?

Comment: what it is currently showing

Comment: I'm unable to sum these aliases

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag your question with it.

Comment: could you please add your current result in the question

Comment: You can not use an alias you defined in the same SELECT if that is what you mean

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT query with CASE condition and SUM()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935265/select-query-with-case-condition-and-sum). It is actually **EXACTLY** the same query. Same table, same columns, same everyhing

Comment: write more details of your problem please

Comment: sql server 2014

Comment: if you want total then add  sum(Camount)  in select

Comment: Can you do just one SUM where the IF statement's condition is: CPaymentType='Check' OR CPaymentType='Cash'?

Answer (score 0):

You can add those two fields with derived option like the below:

```
SELECT PaymentAmountCheck, 
      PaymentAmountCash, 
      PaymentAmountCheck + PaymentAmountCash AS TotalAmount
FROM (
 Select SUM(IIF(CPaymentType='Check', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCheck, 
       SUM(IIF(CPaymentType='Cash', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCash,
 from TableOrderPayment 
 where CPaymentType IN ('Check','Cash') and CDate<=SYSDATETIME() and CStatus='Active';
) AS Q;
```

Also in SQL Server, you may use [`IIF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: hey I have used case in place of IIF and that's worked perfectly Thanks for the help but when I am trying to use more columns then it is giving the error

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Done with it Thanks for the help.

Comment: If it solve your problem, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/312043)

Answer (score 0):

Since in the where clause you have mentioned `CPaymentType`  you can just add `sum(CAmount)` in `select` that will give you sum of `PaymentAmountCheck` and `PaymentAmountCash` .

```
  Select SUM(IF(CPaymentType='Check', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCheck, 
           SUM(IF(CPaymentType='Cash', CAmount, 0)) as PaymentAmountCash ,
           sum(CAmount) total
    from TableOrderPayment 
    where CPaymentType IN ('Check','Cash') and CDate<=SYSDATETIME() and CStatus='Active';
```