# What is the best way to sum data over multiple date ranges in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sum

I have a table containing a *user id*, *purchase amount*, and *date*. I need to calculate the sum over several periods, for the same user. For example, given:

| UserId | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-03 | 10 |
| 1 | 2021-01-10 | 20 |
| 1 | 2021-02-07 | 30 |

From an API, for the same user, I might need to sum and return all of the following ranges:

| Description | Range | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The first week of Jan | 1st (Friday) to the 3rd (Sunday) | 10 |
| The month of Jan | 1st to the 31st | 30 |
| The month of Feb | 1st to the 28th | 30 |

Some restrictions:

1. I don't know the dates up front (the consumer either needs calendar periods, or rolling periods), so I don't think I can create curated queries using `SUM` and `CASE`? I saw an [example of this here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20935337/1244630)
2. I also need to use a stored procedure when interacting with the DB, so I wouldn't be able to dynamically create the `SELECT` statement from the API.

I don't have a lot of experiences writing SQL, but I imagine it's better to have a single query that calculates all of the totals than calculating the sums individually? Any suggestions?

Comment: Have the user use a date picker, and then you can just parametrise the start and end dates. Where the date us between the 1st Friday to the 3rd Sunday has no context to SQL Server; it doesn't understand "Englishy" descriptions.

Comment: That works well for a single range, but I need to be able to select multiple ranges over the same data. Apologies, I've updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: So you want to pass multiple date ranges, at the same time? Use a table type parameter with 2 columns, a start date and an end date, and `JOIN` to that.

Comment: Thank you :) I'm not yet sure how to do that but I'll give it a try and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Larnu, this seems to work, where `Range` is passed in as a table, and `Purchases` is the table listed in the question:

```sql
SELECT r.StartDate,
       r.EndDate,
       SUM(p.Amount) AS Total
FROM Range r
JOIN Purchases p ON p.Date >= r.StartDate
                AND p.Date < r.EndDate
GROUP BY r.StartDate, r.EndDate;
```

Which results in:

| StartDate | EndDate | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 10 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 30 |
| 2021-02-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 30 |

Will this query perform reasonably well? Or is there perhaps a better way to do this?

Comment: This should be efficient if `Purchases` is properly indexed `Date INCLUDE (Amount)`. You can use a Table Parameter for `@Range`, make sure that is indexed also `StartDate, EndDate`. I note the correct use of the half-open interval for date comparisons `>= AND <`